# Create new user for free MySQL database hosted on Azure (root access)

Tags: mysql, database, azure, mysql-workbench

I created a new MySQL database named "guestbook" using the **free "Merkury" pricing level** in the Azure Portal and I connected to it using MySQL Workbench using the username and password shown on Azure.
Just connecting works fine, but it seems like the **provided user does not have the rights to add new MySQL users**.

SQL Query:

```
USE guestbook;
CREATE USER 'gb-webserver'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<PASSWORD>';

===> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

**How do I create a new MySQL user on a MySQL database that is hosted on Azure?**

Comment: I've not used Azure but: Pretty sure it is a shared server and you can't. I'm sure it depends on what version of the service you chose, but the low-end ones would almost certainly be shared.

Comment: I'm using the free "Merkury" pricing level, but I can't find any notes that the database is shared. I think you meant websites, which can be hosted on shared servers but this doesn't apply in my case.

Comment: Nope, I don't mean web sites, I mean databases, because that is how nearly everyone does it. I speak from having used several other services before.

Comment: On ClearDB's site under the FAQ about multi-tenant databases: "This means that you have reached the size limit on your database. This typically happens with our *free database plan*, where a maximum of 5-10MB is allowed." - So the free plan is multi-tenant.

Comment: You are right, the database is multi-tenant! But I don't think maxing out my available storage space is the problem here, the database is nearly empty (~80 KB) and inserts work, only the user creation fails.

Comment: I didn't say you're maxing out your storage. I'm saying that usually when you have a multi-tenant DB, you do not have rights to create users. You aren't granted them by the provider.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding regarding the maxed out storage. I guess I just have to accept that I can't create any users because the DB is multi-tenant then. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is **not possible** to create new users or get root access to MySQL databases hosted on Azure, at least not when **using the free "Merkury" pricing level**.